# Save MQTT output to file with Python

Tags: python, json, mqtt

I have my MQTT subscriber and need to save output I tried with different options but not working. As you can see I did different type of tests.

```
# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    #print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))
    #data = on_message() --no working 
    with open('data.json', 'a') as f:
        print('file.txt', file=f)
        #json.dump(data, f)
        #f.write(print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload)))

#data = on_message()
#with open ('data.json', 'w') as f:
#  json.dump(data, f)
```

Comment: what do you think `data = on_message()` is supposed to do?

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72898962/edit) the question, do not try to add code to comments

Answer (score 0):

I did it work like this, if theres any best way please let me know. thanks.

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    d = json.loads(msg.payload.decode("utf-8"))    
    with open("file.txt", "a+") as f:
        with redirect_stdout(f):
            print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))
```

Comment: Sorry - I'm not clear if this solved your issue or "did it" is a typo and you meant to say "didn't"? Either way you can remove the `json.loads` line because you are not using the result.

Comment: Yes I did,, sorry it was fixt and I changed the file.txt to file.json. thanks !